# How to change code from fragment to activity

Tags: android-activity

I am new to android and have faced some problem, I am making a StudentArraylist to view the student from my firebase database to show them in ListView. But I face some problem because the code I have now I meant for fragment but not activity and
Here is my error
This is the ViewStudentActivity

```
    StudentArrayList adapter = new StudentArrayList(getActivity(),studentList);
            studentlist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

2. This is the StudentArrayList:

   ```
   public StudentArrayList(Activity context, List<Student>studentList){
   super(context, R.layout.student_list, studentList);
   this.context = context;
   this.studentList = studentList;
   }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull 
   ViewGroup parent) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

   View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_list, null, true);
   s_sid = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtSid);
   s_name = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
   s_email = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
   s_fyp = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.s_fyp);
   btnUpdate = (Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
   firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   pdatabaseReference  = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
   auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

   final Student student = studentList.get(position);

   s_sid.setText("Student ID : " + student.gets_sid());
   s_name.setText("Student Name : " +student.gets_name());
   s_email.setText("Date : " +student.gets_email());
   s_fyp.setText("Time Start : " +student.gets_fyp());


   return listViewItem;

   }
   ```